# quasi-uniformisation of bitopological spaces

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

By a well-known result of [Pervin](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01440953?LI=true) every topological space is quasi-uniformisable. Since a quasi-uniformity always induces two topologies, one naturally obtains from a quasi-uniform space a bitopological space. Are there known conditions which characterise those bitopological spaces that arise from a quasi-uniform space? In other words, let $F\colon QUnif \to BTop$ be the evident functor assigning a bitopological space to a quasi-uniform space. Can one characterise the essential image of $F$ in terms of the given topologies comprising a bitopological space?

Comment: Hi Ittay, can you expand a bit on how this works: 'Since a quasi-uniformity always induces two topologies...'? I tried googling it, but this blog post seems to only define 1 topology from the quasi-uniformity: https://projects.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/topology/?page_id=2869 and other sources are paywalled

Comment: Or maybe I am misunderstanding the blog and there are really two topologies there. I never heard about quasi-uniformities before and it is a lot to take in at once...